# Running bundle w/ no command

Tags: bundler

What command is being run when you call `bundle`? Is it just calling `bundle install` under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just running `bundle` calls the bundle script with it's last parameter-set.
Suppose, in your project, you initially did `bundle install` and then changed your Gemfile. To update the gems, you need not repeat `bundle install` again (though, you still can), you can simply run:

```
bundle
```

Similarly, if you initially used `bundle install --binstubs` (with binstubs flag), using `bundle` later in the project, will trigger the former command again.

Good luck. :)

Comment: what do you mean by "with its last parameter-set?"